# Replace Number Strings in Text File

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, numbers, port

I need a code in VBScript or batch to replace 5 Caracters (the bold numbers below) in a line of a text file to change ports numbers.

`change_port.vbs`:

```
prefsFile = "%userprofile%\Desktop\teste.msrcincident"
prefsFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings(prefsFile)

newPrefs = "5500"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

json = fso.OpenTextFile(prefsFile).ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "":*?",*,"

json = re.Replace(json, ": & newPrefs & ",*,")

fso.OpenTextFile(prefsFile, 2).Write(json)
```

Original text file:

```
RCTICKET="65538,1,10.0.0.1:54593,*,ucIdnri2n4QPf/bv92mtx4w2qliCNdyDgBpHPr7nJFdxYL2/dR+iel9Mh4zgD6QR,*,*,Fbjf5rcIrdrlnibnisrzRcO8tsY=" PassStub="HG)7HbhIZPTiKy" RCTICKETENCRYPTED="1" DtStart="1457700115" DtLength="142560" L="0"/></UPLOADINFO>
```

Expected result text file:

```
RCTICKET="65538,1,10.0.0.1:5500,*,ucIdnri2n4QPf/bv92mtx4w2qliCNdyDgBpHPr7nJFdxYL2/dR+iel9Mh4zgD6QR,*,*,Fbjf5rcIrdrlnibnisrzRcO8tsY=" PassStub="HG)7HbhIZPTiKy" RCTICKETENCRYPTED="1" DtStart="1457700115" DtLength="142560" L="0"/></UPLOADINFO>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? please share your code! we are not going to do your work for you, we are here to help you with specific programming problems you encounter; take a look also [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search and replacement expressions are messed up. You're looking for a colon (`:`) followed by one or more digits (`\d+` or `[0-9]+`) followed by a comma (`,`), and want to replace that with a colon followed by the new port number and a comma.

Change this:

```
re.Pattern = "":*?",*,"

json = re.Replace(json, ": & newPrefs & ",*,")
```

into this.

```
re.Pattern = ":\d+,"

json = re.Replace(json, ":" & newPrefs & ",")
```

Always keep your expressions as simple as possible.